# Any difference between these two while loops?

Tags: c

```
while ((R_SPI2SR & B_SPIF) != B_SPIF)
{
    SERIAL_SERVICE_WDOG;
};


while ((R_SPI2SR & B_SPIF) != B_SPIF)
{
    SERIAL_SERVICE_WDOG;
}
```

I like to know what is the purpose in putting semicolon..

Answer (score 6):

The semicolon after the first loop is not a part of that loop at all. It is interpreted as a completely independent *empty statement* that sits *between* the loops. I.e. your actual loops are seen as absolutely identical by C language.

Answer (score 5):

The statement executed by the while loop is the compound statement inside the curly braces.  The semicolon is just a gratuitous empty statement.  You could have written this loop as:

```
while ((R_SPI2SR & B_SPIF) != B_SPIF)
    SERIAL_SERVICE_WDOG;
```

since the compound statement just has a single statement inside it, or as

```
while ((R_SPI2SR & B_SPIF) != B_SPIF)
{
    SERIAL_SERVICE_WDOG;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
};;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

which of course is awful style.

An empty statement is used when you have a loop that needs no body.

```
/* Throw away remaining characters up to the end of line. */
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n')
   ;
```

You want to watch out for the classic error of ending a loop prematurely:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
while ( i < 10 );    /* The semicolon here ends the loop... */
    j *= i++;        /* ... so this statement is only executed once. */
```

Unnecessary semicolons are just clutter, so you should never use them.

Answer (score 3):

the only different in the code is the additional semicolon.
but the compiled assembly are the same.